# eigenvalues and eigenvectors for a generalized Pauli matrix in spherical coordinates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-spin, eigenvalue

If we have $nz=\cosθ$, $nx=\sinθ\cosφ$ and $ny = \sinθ\sinφ$,
how we can compute the eigenvectors of the Linear Operator of the spin ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume this is a homework problem, and you are asked to diagonalize your 2x2 matrix
$$
\hat{n}\cdot\vec{\sigma}=  \begin{pmatrix}
      \cos \theta&  e^{-i\phi}\sin \theta \\
    e^{i\phi}  \sin \theta &-\cos \theta
    \end{pmatrix} 
$$
directly, for practice.

The eigenvalues are obviously 1 and -1, corresponding to eigenvectors, respectively, $(\cos (\theta/2),~ e^{i\phi} \sin (\theta /2))$ and     $( - e^{-i\phi }\sin (\theta /2),~ \cos (\theta /2))$ .

I should not spoil the fun of interpreting the answer by rotating from ***z*** to ***n***, so getting the above matrix as $R^{-1} \sigma_z R$, and getting this answer indirectly, utilizing Wigner's *d* matrices, which I imagine you were invited to do...